# Search field is not not working

Tags: django, python-2.7, search, model, admin

I am Using django my model and admin part is given bellow

`Model.py'

```
 class Scrip_Master(models.Model):
    nse_markt_typ = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    bse_markt_typ = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    mcx_sx_markt_typ = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    nse_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    bse_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    mcx_sx_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    isin_code = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    nse_series = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    bse_series = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    mcx_series = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
    nse_dt_listng = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
    bse_dt_listng = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
    face_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, editable=True)

    def nse_date_listng(self):
        if self.nse_dt_listng is not None:
            return self.nse_dt_listng.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        else:
            return self.nse_dt_listng
```

`Admin.py`

```
   class Scrip_MasterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display =   ('nse_markts_typ','nse_symbol','isin_code','nse_series','nse_date_listng','face_value')
       search_fields = ['nse_markt_typ','nse_symbol','isin_code','nse_series','nse_date_listng','face_value']

       def nse_markts_typ(self,obj):
           if MDfile.objects.filter(symbol=obj.nse_symbol).first():    
              nse_markt_typ = MDfile.objects.filter(symbol=obj.nse_symbol).first()   

              return nse_markt_typ.mkt_type
           else:
              return obj.nse_markt_typ
```

In this the nse_markt_typ column don't have any kind off data in and it is referring to another column in another table and populating the result. But here the problem my filters will not work for this field because the displayed data is not in the database so how can achieve filter for this field 
do any one knows a solutions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an easy way to include a property like `nse_markt_typ` in the `search_fields` list.

Would it be possible to change your model to add a foreign key to `MDfile`? Then you can use the double underscore `__` to search a field on the linked object.

```
class Scrip_Master(models.Model):
    nse_markt_typ = models.ForeignKey(MDfile, blank=True, null=True)

class Scrip_MasterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   ...
   search_fields = ['nse_markt_typ__mkt_type', ...]
```

Note that you cannot use `nse_markt_typ__mkt_type` in `list_display`, so you might have to create a property, or use `nse_markt_typ` and set a suitable `__unicode__` for your `MDfile` model.

Comment: can you please show me an example how to do this foreign implementation in admin and models

Comment: i cant assign nse_markt_typ in scrip master as foreign key because I am importing value to scrip master from a file